# Is it possible to create a float type with a min and max range?

Tags: java

I know this can be done in Ada but I'm new to Java and don't know if I can do this.  I would like to make a radian of float subtype from 0 to 2pi.  Values outside the range would be considered out of range and through a constraint error.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

commons.lang.math.Range just specifies the range constraint. It does not represent a value in that range (which I think is what you want).

You could create a new class to hold the value and enforce the constraint. Your own program would pass instances of this class around and would thus get the type safety (of having the constraint enforced). When calling other API, you have to revert back to sending and accepting regular double values. You can check the constraint again before accepting return values.

```
public class Radian extends Number {

     private final double value;

     public Radian(double value){
          if (value < 0 || value >= 2 * PI)
               throw new IllegalArgumentException(value + " is out of range");
          this.value = value;
     }

     public double doubleValue(){
         return value;
     }

     // ... and other methods in the Number interface
     //   don't forget equals and hashCode and toString
}
```

Comment: Why would you want this to be immutable?  Just curious.

Comment: @vlad003: Why would you want to make it mutable? All Number classes in the JDK are immutable.

Comment: I had to use extends instead of implements but besides that this worked as intended.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

There's no Range object built into Java, but you could always use something from Apache Commons http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/math/Range.html

Answer (score 0):

Java has no way to declare an Ada-like subtype of a primitive type, and specifically no way to declare types that are subranges of primitive types.

The best you can do in Java is create a custom wrapper class for a primitive type and have the wrapper enforce the range constraints using (purely) runtime checks.

Comment: If all your code uses the wrapper exclusively, you pretty much get compile-time type safety. Of course, the part where it has to interface with the outside will have to rely on runtime checks.

Comment: The issue is with the range checks; e.g. when you add two constrained numbers together.  In Java these checks can only be performed at runtime. In Ada, a smart compiler could do some of the checks at compile time; e.g. in constant expressions involving range types.